# What is the pramanya of the Naalayira Divya Prabhandham?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, pramana, divya-prabhandham

The [Naalayira Divya Prabhandham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naalayira_Divya_Prabhandham) are 4,000 verses in Tamil spoken by ancient Tamil Vaishnava saints (Alwars) that are revered by Sri Vaishnavas.

They are so important that they are epistemologically considered equivalent to the Vedas in terms of their validity. Sri Vaishnava acharyas routinely cite verses from the Prabhandham to support their philosophical and theological doctrines.

My question is, what is the Pramanya for this?

Shabaracharya's commentary on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras is traditionally considered to establish the Pramanya of the Vedas, and Yamunacharya's *Agama Pramanya* is traditionally considered by Sri Vaishnavas to establish the Pramanya of the Pancharatra Agamas.

So is there something similar that establishes the Pramanya of the Naalayira Divya Prabhandham?

Comment: As far as I know, only Sri Vaishnavas accept the Divya Prabandham as pramana.

Comment: @LazyLubber I know. I'm just asking how Sri Vaishnavas think they're a valid pramana.

Comment: why do we accept Vedas as a valid pramana ?

Comment: @ram Because they are authorless.

Comment: how do we know they are authorless ? and even if they are, why should we accept them ?

Comment: @Ikshvaku - Srivaishnavas accept the Divya Prabandhams because of the perceived non-contradiction with Veda/Vedanta. Is there a specific belief of Srivaishnavas you know of that cannot be sourced from Veda/Vedanta yet is uniquely sourced from the Divya Prabandhams?

Comment: > They are so important that they are epistemologically considered equivalent to the Vedas in terms of their validity.  @Ikshvaku You have got this backward. It is precisely because of their close following of the Vedas that the Divya Prabandhams are considered important and revered; not the other way around.

Comment: @hashable Thanks.

Comment: @ram They are authorless because all the Vedic paramparas either have a recollection of non-authorship, or they don't remember the author when there should have been one, just like how Brahmanas have recollection of their gotras, etc. And this parampara of recollection goes back to Brahma, and the Brahmas before him. And an authorless text is true when it doesn't contradict any other means of knowledge, because then there is nothing that can falsify it.

Comment: @ram An authorless text is more authoritative than a text authored by a very credible person, because there is less possibility of errors compared to an authored text.